# Possible to write video directly to iOS Camera Roll or album without copying?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, camera

I have an iOS app that records videos. I want to place them in the user's Camera Roll, or in an album. However, to do this I must first record them to a temporary directory, ***then copy them*** to the Camera Roll. This means 2x storage space is required. Some videos may fail to copy of the storage on the device is near full.
Is there any way to record directly into an an album? Or am I required to always make the copy?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of video you are capturing, you should investigate the use of `UIImagePickerController`.

A lot of people don't realize that not only does it have a camera-capture mode, but that mode supports video:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/cameracapturemode/video

A couple limitations:

1. This is the older/legacy interface. It is still supported, but has not gotten many revisions for new hardware since the AV* frameworks were added. There maybe newer camera/video features that can't be accessed.
2. The docs do not describe the use of temp files and full disks, so you should still test this feature before committing to its use.
3. It does has a built in "video clip" feature, so users have some ways of limiting their use of storage when capturing the file.